# builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

I'm writing a program for my CS class to calculate the weighted average of a grade, but after trying to run it a couple of times, I continue to get this odd builtins error. I don't know what the problem is, so there's a good chance that the same problem is in some of my other definitions.

```
def main():
    #user inputs grades into a set of lists
    assignmentList = [float(input('assignment scores: ')) for grade in range(14)]
    quizList = [float(input('quiz scores: ')) for grade1 in range(4)]
    wExamList = [float(input('written exam scores: ')) for grade2 in range(2)]
    lExamList = [float(input('lab exam scores: ')) for grade3 in range(2)]
    finalExam = [float(input('final exam score: ')) for grade4 in range(1)]
    print()

    #import the definitions
    gradeAvg = round(assignments(assignmentList) + quizzes(quizList) + writtenExams(wExamList) + labExams(lExamList) + finalExam(finalExam), 2)
    print('Overall grade:', gradeAvg)

    #create elifs to figure out Letter grades
    if gradeAvg <= 93:
        print('Letter grade: A') 
    elif 90 <= gradeAvg > 93:
        print('Letter grade: A-')
    elif 87 <= gradeAvg >89:
        print('Letter grade: B+')
    elif 83 <= gradeAvg > 87:
        print('Letter grade: B')
    elif 80<= gradeAvg > 83:
        print('Letter grade: B-')
    elif 77 <= gradeAvg >80:
        print('Letter grade: C+')    
    elif 73 <= gradeAvg >77:
        print('Letter grade: C') 
    elif 70 <= gradeAvg >73:
        print('Letter grade: C-') 
    elif 67<= gradeAvg >70:
        print('Letter grade: D+')
    elif 60 <= gradeAvg >67:
        print('Letter grade: D')
    else:
        print('Letter grade: F')

def assignments(assignment):
    list1 = [assignment]

    #sort assignments and delete the lowest score
    list1.sort()
    del list1[0]

    #get the weighted average for homework
    assignAvg = sum(list1)
    assignAvg = round((assignAvg / 14) * .25, 2)
    return assignAvg

def quizzes(quiz):
    list2 = [quiz]
    list2.sort()

    #weighted average for quizzes
    quizAvg = (sum(list2))
    quizAvg1 = round((quizAvg / 4) * .15, 2)
    return quizAvg1

def writtenExams(wExam):
    list3 = [wExam]

    #weighted average for written exams
    examAvg = sum(list3)
    examAvg1 = round((examAvg / 2) * .20, 2)
    return examAvg1

def labExams(lExam):
    list4 = [lExam]

    examAvg = sum(list4)
    examAvg2 = round((examAvg / 2) * .20, 2)
    return examAvg2

def finalExam(fExam):
    list5 = [fExam]
    examAvg = sum(list5)
    examAvg3 = round(examAvg * .20, 2)
    return examAvg3

main()
```

The very first instance of the error is on line 66 with 'quizAvg = (sum(list2))'

Comment: I would like to know how the `quizzes(quiz)` function is called and what its parameter contains. Also, why do you always run a line like `listN = [argument]`?

Comment: part of this assignment was to use list comprehensions, so I went kinda heavy on it

Comment: This is not a list comprehension, it's just a list literal with another list as content. It's absolutely wrong where and how you use it.

Comment: `90 <= gradeAvg > 93` - Any number greater than 93 will necessarily be greater than 90 as well, by the way.

Comment: I'd rather not do the whole for loop .append thing and this cut down on some typing. But to answer your question, 'quizzes(quiz) gets called in main under the gradeAvg object

Comment: You can also cut down on typing by replacing the whole program with `pass`, but that won't produce correct results, either. I suggest that you review the course materials on comprehensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quizList` is a `list`. You pass it to `quizzes()`. Then you do `list2 = [quiz]`. Not only does this not produce a separate copy of `quiz`, it wraps it in another `list`. You'd get something like this:

```
[[1, 3, 3, 2, 4]]
```

This means that when you send it to `sum()`, it tries to add the first element onto the default start value of 0, which means it's doing `0 + [1, 3,...]` internally - and there's where it adds an `int` and a `list`.

Instead, make a separate copy to sort, and don't change the structure:

```
list2 = sorted(quiz)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out. But just wondering, why didn't the error first appear under 'def assignments'? I did essentially the same thing there

Comment: @AllenJunge: Because you deleted the first element of a single element `list` (`del list[0]`), so the `sum` was operating on `[]`, it never had anything to add to the starting `0`.

Comment: so that was all well and good, but now it's returning another TypeError ''list' object is not callable' for gradeAvg in main